# How to get SharePoint designer online workflow subscriptionId

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I would like to use rest api to trigger my manual workflows from a list.
Would like users to select some various items and click a button and then trigger the workflow on each items

I have this url below

```
/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={08012d13-3b9f-446b-87a6-a616a4906cc0}&ID=1&ItemGuid={7C2E6668-E4AC-4A54-89DA-5D0DE9907CAE}&TemplateID={44caed28-e898-4472-82ce-8e9fac8bfabf}
```

But I don't get to see the subscriptionId parameter. Is it the same as the TemplateID?

The REST api I am using is as follows:

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='44caed28-e898-4472-82ce-8e9fac8bfabf',itemId=2)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Using workflow 2010 or 2013? 2010 has an templateID (changes everytime you publish). 2013 has subscriptionID

Comment: Thanks Peter about SP Online?

Comment: Did you create the workflow with SharePoint Designer?

Comment: check the link that you get when you want to start the workflow

Comment: Thanks Peter. I taught you were referring to SP versions..Yes i was using 2010 workflows but when i created 2013 workflows i could now see the subscriptionids. Is there a way to achieve the same when using SP 2010 workflows?

Comment: No, WF 2010 works with "templateid". But this id changes everytime you publish the workflow. Does not work with API

Answer (score 0):

You could go to list settings-> workflow settings, click the workflow. You would see the workflow subscriptionId in the URL.

Comment: Hi Michael, Does this work for SP online?

Comment: Hi Michael, When i do this - You could go to list settings-> workflow settings, click the workflow. This wants to open the workflow in SP Designer.. Not sure where you are seeing the subscriptionid here..

Comment: As Peter mentioned the subscriptionid is only available in SP 2013 workflows

Comment: Yes, subscriptionid is only in workflow 2013. The rest api would not work for workflow 2010.